# Can not able to fetch the data from DB while consuming API in ReactJS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-fullstack

I have one query that while consuming API my records inside Department table is not getting displayed. When I am hitting the Department buttton in NavBar then the 2 columns of table i.e DepartmentId and DepartmentName are displaying but the records are not displaying inside the table or we can say it is not able to fetch the data from database.

So basically my issue is that I am not able to fetch the data from database, please explain me how to fix it..

1) URL-c# generating API-
   [image: Generating API]
2)React weppage (Here error is that records are not getting fetch in table in UI 
  after consuming the 
    API):-
  [image: Consuming API in React side]

3)React---Department.JS(Not getting  records inside this table in web page) 
  could not able to fetch the data from database.
   [image: Table records in UI]

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to be able to solve this problem.  The first three links you've provided are of the same screenshot.  We need to see the code to be able to know whats happening, not the front end visuals.  Did you try logging the api info to the console?  is it showing up?  if not then it's either the way the api is sending the data that is wrong, or the way you're consuming it.  If it is showing up then you're more than likely not formatting it or sending it to react in the proper way.  I can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Yaa sorry that was my mistake.. now I have edited and added the code now can u please check it and let me know my errors..

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting parens around your tr and td block, like so:

```
     <tbody>
      {deps.map(dep => (
        <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
          <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
          <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work...is my issue is coming because I am using VPN?

Comment: @Code_is_Fun I'm not sure, just try switching your VPN off and test.

Comment: Yes @GCQ but still not working this type of error is coming in console can u please check..

Comment: Yes @GCQ error is coming like --Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch data, can u please help how to rectify this kind of error..